# Strange "frozen" content of WPF Window bug

Tags: wpf, window

A few of my users are experiencing a strange bug. I have a simple WPF window that contains a few textblocks and buttons. After a short time using my application successfully the users that experience the problem report that the window's content becomes empty and only the border of the window is visible.

After remoting onto their machines I have confirmed that it looks like the content of the window is frozen. When the window first opens it appears like its see through and displays whatever is behind it. If I move the window around the same frozen image of what was behind the window when it opened stays there. If I bring something in front of the Windows (such as a browser) the "frozen image" in the contents will change to a frozen image of whatever was in front of it. I have discovered that the buttons are still active and clickable in the window, so it's not completely frozen it just seems not to be drawing the content properly.

The issue only seems to affect a small percentage of my users and I cannot recreate this issue on any of my test machines. Any ideas about what is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you narrowed down what the users have in common? Same operating system? Same graphics card?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a user that's willing to experiment to find a solution, have them [Disable Hardware Acceleration in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970912.aspx#disablehardwareacceleration).  If this fixes the issue, then it's most likely a graphics driver problem.